# Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my project, I have got a partial view with the following block of code doing some conditions like this:

```
@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.FirstName)) {
    <h3>  @Model.FirtsName </h3>
}
```

Just as simple as that. When I run my project, a null model is returned. I get the following error:

`Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference`

I thought I had already defined this in my `if` statement.

Is there anything that I am missing?

Comment: first of all, remove `@` from `Model` and then make sure `Model` is not null

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your code, you only check the `FirstName` property for null or empty values, but not the model itself. You need to add a check for the model also:

```
@if (Model != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.FirstName)){
    <h3>  @Model.FirstName </h3>
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH THIS WORKED!! i shall accept the answer when it lets me! I appreciate it very much

Answer (score 0):

If there is no error on cshtml page, close and reopen again. Probably intellisense shows error exact line.